# Expanding functions with poles in QFT Calculation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, calculus, dimensional-regularization

I am using Series function in Mathematica on $(1/z)(-k^2)^z$. Up to $z^0$, the function gives me $1/z + \log[-k^2]$. But in the standard textbook on QFT, it turns out the expansion should give $1/z + \log[k^2/\mu^2] -i\pi $ up to $z^0$ in the series. Could you explain the reason behind such discrepancy? How to resolve it?

Comment: `Series[1/z (-k^2)^z, {z, 0, 0}] // Normal // ComplexExpand`. Then, the $i\pi$ versus $-i\pi$ is a matter of a choice of branch cut of the logarithm, which you can do by hand.  There are ways to tell *Mathematica* how to choose a branch cut: for instance, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14813/moving-the-location-of-the-branch-cut-in-mathematica.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the function $a^x$ simply does not make sense if $a$ is a dimensionful parameter. To correctly deal with your problem, you should introduce a dimensionful parameter $\mu$ and then consider the function
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{z} \left( \frac{-k^2}{\mu^2} \right)^z
$$
This is a perfectly well-defined function. Expanding this at small $z$, we get
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \ln\left( \frac{-k^2}{\mu^2} \right) + O(z) . 
$$
The way you deal with the $-$ sign in the argument of the $\ln$ depends on your chosen branch cut structure.

Note that if you do all the calculations in physics *correctly*, you will NEVER get a function of the form $(-k^2)^z$, you'll only ever get $(-k^2/\mu^2)^z$.

Answer (score 2):

Just note that $(-k^2)^z = e^{z\ln(-k^2)} = 1 + z \ln(-k^2) + \mathcal{O}(z^2)$ and $\ln(-k^2) = ln\left(e^{-i\pi}k^2\right) = \ln(k^2) - i\pi$ which just depends on the branch of the complex logarithm that you choose. The $\mu^2$ is introduced as a scale, since the logarithm of a dimensionful quantity does not make sense. So you then get $$\frac{1}{z}\left(-k^2\right)^z = \frac{1 + z(\ln(k^2) - i\pi) + \mathcal{O}(z^2)}{z} = \frac{1}{z} + \ln(k^2) - i\pi + \mathcal{O}(z)$$

Comment: Thank you so very much for the vivid feedback. A follow up question is, I understand that instead of -i*pi, I could also choose +i*pi. Does it have anything to do with the prescription for the poles this (-k^2)^z is coming from, like the Feynman prescription, or the retarded, advanced prescriptions. Or do I have freedom of choosing i*pi or -i*pi regardless of such prescriptions for the poles in the propagators whatsoever. Any particular example or reference would be very much appreciated as well. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I don't know anything about that. But I would venture to guess that as long as you use the same convention everywhere it shouldn't matter.